# Bootstrap buttons and text relative and vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

I am trying to make something similar to the below image via **bootstrap 4**.

[image]

You can assume that the black rectangle is the window, the green is a `div` with the three elements inside, it should be vertically in the center, the red is text and the oranges are two buttons.

This is my code but it doesn't work:

The three elements should stack in rows if the window width is too small.

```html
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <span class="btn-projects scrollto">blablablablablablasalkadfjklasd</span>
    <span class="row justify-content-md-center">
      <span class="col-s-2">
        <a href="/" class="btn-get-started scrollto"><i class="fa fa-google"
            style="color:tomato;margin-left:4px;"></i></a>
      </span>
      <span class="col-s-2">
        <a href="/" class="btn-get-started scrollto"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"
            style="color:tomato;margin-left:4px;"></i></a>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: You want the text to be in the middle of both the buttons then add  text span in between two buttons.

Comment: You said-  **I have done some code**, can you please share what you have done?

Comment: @Tanim The code is written !

Comment: you meant something like this https://codepen.io/Tanim_Mahbub/pen/MWeGjJp?editors=1000 ?

Comment: wasn't intentional, I was trying to see the activity, clicked on that accidentally

Comment: @Tanim, if you didn't meant to downvote you can retract it.

Comment: I tried, not happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to use bootstrap is to use the `col` and `row` bootstrap classes to map the content to the page, in your case a nice way to do it would be to create a `row` and inside of it create 3 columns using `col` class, to align I'd just use plain old styling to vertical and horizontal align the contents:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="row" style="border: 2px solid black;height:150px;padding:0;margin:0">
  <div class="col-sm-12" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center">
    <div class="row"
      style="border: 1px solid green;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;text-align:center">
      <span class="col-sm-2">
        <a href="/" class="btn-get-started scrollto"> <i class="fa fa-md fa-google" style="color:tomato;"></i></a>
      </span>
      <span class="col-sm-8" style="border: 1px solid red">blablablablablabla</span>
      <span class="col-sm-2">
        <a href="/" class="btn-get-started scrollto"> <i class="fa fa-md fa-linkedin" style="color:tomato;"></i></a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The code is basically the same as yours with the propper rearrangements and the center styling, the height of the sample is set to `150px` for sample purposes, but you can set it to `100%` or whatever height you wish in your project. The `col` relative proportions I used are also for demonstration purposes, you can, of course, use whatever dimensions you need.

I just added the propper external linkage so the snippet can be ran.

Note that the inline styling is also for sample purposes, you can/should place these in a style sheet.

Comment: Thanks but buttons are not inside the container ( green rectangle) also I want to with all size ( except if it is to small) they show in a row

Comment: @Sam, so you just add the due classes to the spans, I edited the answer.

Comment: @Sam, Glad to help, I did edit the answer further, I think now is more in line with what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Add width to `child two` to set fixed width.

```css
.black {
    border: 1px black solid;
    padding: 5% 10%;
    margin: 10%;
}
.main {
    border: 1px green solid;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
}
.child{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0px;
}
.child.one:hover,
.child.three:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #efefef;
}
.child.one{
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px #ff9800 solid;
    text-align: center;
}
.child.two{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px red solid;
}
.child.three{
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px #ff9800 solid;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="black">
    <div class="main">
        <a class="child one">G</a>
        <div class="child two">Hurraaayyy!</div>
        <a class="child three">G</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage *width* inside row according to these predefined classes **col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-6 col-xl-5**. So there is no need inline CSS.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center border border-dark p-5">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
      <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center border border-success text-center">
        <span class="col-2">
          <a href="/" class="text-warning">
            <i class="fa fa-md fa-star"></i>
          </a>
        </span>
        <span class="col-8 border border-danger">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </span>
        <span class="col-2">
          <a href="/" class="text-warning">
            <i class="fa fa-md fa-star"></i>
          </a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```